Apache Airflow - role 'postgres' does not exist
Broken DAG: [/Users/lorenzofilippini/workspace/moodytube_airflow/dags/main.py]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lorenzofilippini/workspace/moodytube_airflow/src/db.py", line 13, in <module>
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/lorenzofilippini/workspace/moodytube_airflow/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist

I created the connection in the admin panel, and I installed the postgres package for Airflow, but even though I created the connection, I get this error with my DAG.

This question is similar to: psql: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
